# Sending Client Certificate in HttpWebRequest

Tags: .net-3.5, x509certificate

I am trying to pass a client certificate to a server using the code below however I still revive the HTTP Error 403.7 - Forbidden: SSL client certificate is required.  What are the possible reasons the HttpWebRequest would not send the client certificate?

```
var clientCertificate = new X509Certificate2( @"C:\Development\TestClient.pfx", "bob" );

                    HttpWebRequest tRequest = ( HttpWebRequest )WebRequest.Create( "https://ofxtest.com/ofxr.dll" );

                    tRequest.ClientCertificates.Add( clientCertificate );
                    tRequest.PreAuthenticate = true;
                    tRequest.KeepAlive = true;
                    tRequest.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
                    tRequest.Method = "POST";
                    var encoder = new ASCIIEncoding();
                    var requestData = encoder.GetBytes( "<OFX></OFX>" );

                    tRequest.GetRequestStream().Write( requestData, 0, requestData.Length );
                    tRequest.GetRequestStream().Close();

                    ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = new System.Net.Security.RemoteCertificateValidationCallback( CertPolicy.ValidateServerCertificate );
                    WriteResponse( tRequest.GetResponse() );
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue appeared to be that some systems did not have an intermediate certificate Authority that this certificate depended on.  It's odd also because this certificate's pfx file did carry both certs.

Comment: In particular, I've found that if the client cert is not signed by an authority that's in the server's trusted CA list, the server acts as though the client cert wasn't sent. Presumably this is on the basis that it has no way of knowing whether the cert provides any useful kind of authentication. (But it's very annoying if you have application logic for verifying that validity of particular certs.)

Answer (score 0):

It could be the wrong cert, could be missing cert, etc.. Use Fiddler (free) as a proxy to intercept the traffic, and you'll see whether the cert is attached or not.

Comment: I have used fiddler and I see no indication of the client cert on the initial connect request.  I have this cert working in an mfc test application so it seems to be something with .net not liking something.

Comment: You can use SoapUI to make a sample request, and attach the .pfx to it (see Preferences | SSL, and you can attach a .pfx there).  Examine that request through Fiddler, and you'll see what a good one should look like.

Answer (score 0):

Is the password correct?  I'm not familiar with the .net way of doing this, but I assume "bob" is the password.  Change to "rick" and see if you get an error. If so, then you're probably doing it right. If everything is the same as if you use "bob", then there may be an issue with the password.